# How to get Mac OS computer name in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, process

For windows it's `console.log(process.env['COMPUTERNAME'])`;

But how to do it for Mac OS?

Comment: Did you try with `HOSTNAME`?

Comment: I did a console log of process.env and the computer name is not there

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the `os`-module:

```
var os = require('os')
console.log(os.hostname())
```

This is the best way to get the hostname.